# Showing that if $ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sin(nx)=0$, then...

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

let be $ x \in \mathbb{R} $

I want to show that if 
$$  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sin(nx)=0 $$
then $$\sin(x)=0 $$

Do you have any ideas for ways to prove it?
I don't know how to get there..
maybe using the fact that $\sin(a+b)= \sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)..$ ?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\sin (n+1)x=\sin (nx)\cos x+\cos (nx) \sin x$. So $\sin (nx) \to 0$ implies that $cos (nx) \sin x \to 0$. If $\sin x \neq 0$ this gives $ \cos (nx) \to 0$. But then $1=\sin^{2}(nx)+\cos^{2} (nx) \to 0$ , a contradiction.